# Proper style for Github naming conventions

Tags: github

I am new to the world of open source and just set up my Github account. I was wondering if there any naming conventions/styling guides to follow when naming things such a repositories. For example, in Python, there is snake_case. How should I name my repos?

Thanks!

Comment: A duplicate can be found at Stackoverflow: [Is there a naming convention for git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11947587/45249)

Comment: Short answer - no, there is no standard naming convention for git repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Conventions are likely to exist mostly within one programming community, e.g. people who use a given programming language, toolkit or framework, rather than across Github.

For the example of Python, I'd suggest looking at the names of repos linked from popular packages in [PyPI](https://pypi.org/).